# Ubuntu 15.10 freezes on viewing YouTube video on full screen using Google Chrome

Tags: 15.10, video, google-chrome, intel-graphics

The case:

1. Launch Google Chrome.
2. Open YouTube video using the 720p resolution with 60 fps.
3. Make it full screen.
4. Use the "system volume up" hotkey.

After step 3 the video is frozen, but sound continues to play. I can only open console using "CTRL+F1" hotkey and reboot the PC.

Another unstable case, that brings the same result:

1. Launch Google Chrome.
2. Open YouTube video using the 720p resolution with 60 fps.
3. Make it full screen.
4. Exit full screen.

I'm using Intell HD Graphics with new drivers, but the same case was when I used default Ubuntu's driver.

The Google Chrome version: 49.0.2623.87 (64-bit)

The same situation repeats on three different PCs. These cases do not repeat on Firefox.

Can someone confirm the same bug on his PC? Is there some way to resolve (or temporarily resolve) this problem?

Comment: Cannot reproduce on 14.04 LTS: Chrome Version 49.0.2623.87 (64-bit) (works flawlessly) on kernel 3.13.0-79-generic

Answer (score 0):

I've found a lot of similar situations, but not the same. The fix, like using BETA version of Google Chrome does not help here. The fix with disabling "Override software rendering list" in [chrome://flags](http://chrome://flags) also does not help.

In my case, the disabling the flag "Use hardware acceleration when available" in Settings -> Advanced Settings -> System fixes the problem. The full answer, which has helped me is [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/579141/512542). But, I think, this is a **temporarily** solution.

UPDATED. **On Ubuntu 16.04 this bug has been fixed.**

Answer (score 0):

I solved it unchecking the "using hardware acceleration when available" option, on Chrome settings.

Source: https://askubuntu.com/a/579141/215357

Answer (score -1):

Oh!! You have the same problem as mine!

#### Solution:

#### If it freezes:

Force-restart your computer. You can do that by pressing and holding the power button on your device until it shuts down, then turning it on again.

#### To avoid it next time:

Make the volume level the one you like while the video is not yet in Full Screen mode, wait for 10 or so seconds into the video, then full screen it. If you want to see the start of it in full screen, then simply rewind the video all the way to the start.

Comment: So is avoiding really a "solution"?