# Freeze when going to fullscreen on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, freeze, fullscreen

Ubuntu 16.04

Integrated intel graphics

Like title says, sometimes when going to fullscreen in Chrome or Chromium the program freezes. Video (Youtube and Netflix so far) still plays since I can hear it but nothing else. I can move desktops and shortcuts work but I eventually go to terminal and use xkill to kill Chrome.

Any ideas? Never found an answer with the search function.

Comment: Probably a problem with graphics driver and window manager. There have been similar reports http://askubuntu.com/questions/577455/fullscreen-chrome-video-causes-ubuntu-to-crash, and I'm experiencing the same problem. Workaround seems to be to disable hardware acceleration for Chrome.

Answer (score 4):

There is 2 ways to half-solving this problem :

1st - is to disable hardware acceleration in Chrome, but this will decrease performance. (blurry scrolling and vertical lines)

2nd - Open videos in Firefox.

If anyone has a better solution please post here. Tx a lot.